# declared package "com.spade" does not match the expected package "" in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

What that error mean's and how should I resolve it. When i go to `spade/android/app/src/main/java/com/spade/MainApplication.java` it gives me that error.
MainApplication.java code

```
package com.spade;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
....
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
....
}
```

app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
....
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spade"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.spade">
```

Comment: share app/build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml file also

Comment: check updated question